# mongodb datafiles size and occupy memory up to 99% without stopping

Tags: mongodb

When I using MongoDB, I use df -h shell command and it shows the memory is occupied by 99%, I know it is because MongoDB's datafiles. But what I wonder is that why MongoDB server is still running other than stop when occupy memory up to 99%. 
Thanks in advance for good help.

Comment: This is not a programming related question. You will have better luck asking this at Server Fault.

Comment: Take a look at the [storage FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#how-do-i-know-when-the-server-runs-out-of-disk-space). Do you see log messages like that? mongod keeps running with reduced functionality when there's no more disk space.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to have a different opinion, this is a programming related question. Most instances of MongoDB tend to have higher disk usage because of denormalized data model(redundant data).Another reason is MongoDB preallocates Journal files which can run into few gigabytes. Try to use --smallfiles option when mongod starts up. You can also disable journaling altogether , but it is not recommended.